# How do I show this matrix is rank deficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

The 100x100 matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is given by $\sin((i-1)*100 + (j-1))$. I.e the first row is $\sin(1), \sin(2), \sin(3), \sin(4), ... \sin(100)$, second row is $\sin(101), \sin(102, ..., \sin(200)$ etc. I think it must be rank deficient by a trigonometric identity but im having trouble seeing why.

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(100(i-1)+j)$ or $\sin(100(i-1)+(j-1))$? The latter has as its first row the vector $(\sin0,\sin1,\ldots,\sin99)$ that appears in my answer. The argument works more or less the same for either version though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following two vectors
$$
\vec{u}=(\cos0,\cos1,\cos2,\ldots,\cos99)
$$
and
$$
\vec{v}=(\sin0,\sin1,\sin2,\ldots,\sin99).
$$
We have the trig identity
$$
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta.
$$
Consequently the $i$th row of your matrix ($i$ fixed, $j$ ranging from $1$ to $100$) is
$$
\sin(100(i-1))\vec{u}+\cos(100(i-1))\vec{v}.
$$
This means that all the rows of your matrix are in the linear span of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. In other words, the row space of your matrix has dimension $\le2$.